# Load many php-files within controller and situational call them

Tags: php, slack-api

I have another question related to a project of mine. Consider the following scenario.

**Scenario**

- I want to build a Slack App from scratch (to learn something about it)
- it will be used for a Slash Command and to send daily updates to a given channel at a given time (via cronjob). So I will most probably provide a `config.json` and add the modules I want to call when the cronjob triggers the bot.
- The bot class builds the bot and also sets up a `sendToSlack`function (does the curl stuff)
- In the `listen` function the bot listens to certain keywords (eg. `keyword1`) and then execute a certain function. This function gets data from an API. Each keyword he can listen to has its own API-logic.

It would probably be easy to build it with [Botkit](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit) and node, but I want to stick to PHP and do it on my own.

**My questions**

- How can I load multiple modules (eg. from the `/modules` directory) in my Slack-App controller (eg. `controller.php`)?
- What is the best way to then "loop" through all the modules I have loaded and if the module says "Hey that is me" (in other words `keyword === module.keyword`) execute their main function. This main function will get the results from the API and return it back to the controller. The controller will append it to the `$outputText` variable and at the end use the `sendToSlack` function to send it to Slack.

Puh, I hope this is it and I did not forget something so far. Do you - hopefully - know what I am talking about? I am happy to answer questions you have and hopefully you can help me.

Comment: Why would you want to dynamically load modules to deal with different functionality? Are you worried about memory? I would rather suggest to structure your logic into meaningful classes and let PHP deal with the rest. But if you must: You can include scripts conditionally, e.g. put [include_once](http://php.net/manual/de/function.include-once.php) behind an if statement. However I would consider that bad design.

Comment: Hi @ErikKalkoken. Thank you for your answer.  I was pretty sure I did not really describe it very well. Let me try it this way/again. What I need or want is something similar like this:

- Load all skills/modules in a certain folder: https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-facebook/blob/master/bot.js#L65-L68
- Each module/skill handles a certain keyword/trigger: https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-facebook/blob/master/skills/sample_conversations.js#L14

Do you know what I mean?